# Change Video <object> to <iframe>

Tags: php, html, iframe

This is my code, it
s in a joomla template. It plays videos in Flash on browsers and Iframe on Iphones or Ipads. How can I change is so that browsers use iframe instead of flash object?

```html
function showVimeo($vimeo_link, $width, $height)
 {
 
  $num = str_replace('http://vimeo.com/','',$vimeo_link);
  $num = trim($num); 
 
  $iPhone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
  $iPad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
  if ($iPhone == true || $iPad ==true) 
  {
   return '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$num.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" frameborder="0"></iframe>'; 
  }
  else
  {   
   return  '<object width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'">'.
     '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />'.
     '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />'.
     '<param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id='.$num.'&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=1&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" />'.
     '<embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id='.$num.'&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=1&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"></embed>'.
     '</object>';
  }
```

Comment: You could just get rid of the whole if statement and just use the `return` with the iframe.

Comment: Thanks, but the browser part has allow full screen, auto play etc. I found this code and I know I have to change the src part.<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID?portrait=0&color=00ADEF" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>